# Exception during java execution:extraneous input '\r\n \r\nExamples:' expecting {<EOF>, SCENARIO, SCENARIO_OUTLINE, TAGS, NEWLINE}

Tags: cucumber, karate

Here's the feature file. I am just not that familiar with this framework to be able to offer them any advice. About all I tell them is that the issue is with Examples. Is this a file encoding issue? (\r\n \r\n)?

```
@common @account_search
Feature: Account Search
  As a producer
  I want to search for an account
  So that I can review or update the account and associated policies

  @DesignatedFunction
  Scenario Outline: Search for an account with account holder's name
    Given a Personal account with "<filename>" name
    When I search for that account with the account holder's "<filename>" name
    Then the account is found
    Examples:
      |filename       |
      |createAccount  |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Cucumber file. Karate is not Cucumber, read the docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#script-structure